# One to mapping between to composite primary keys jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I do have a use case two tables are having composite primary key, one table have relation with another table in database , how to get that relationship in program level , how to declare the bean class

//Composite primary key of the table Project

```
    @Embeddable
    @Data
    public class ProjectId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 12233365L;

        @Column(name = "PROJECT_CODE")
        private Integer pCode;

        @Column(name = "BOL")
        private String bol;

        @Column(name = "BOLS")
        private String bols;

        @Column(name = "EID")
        private Integer eId;

    }
```

//Project class

```
public class Project implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 748569L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectId projectId;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DATE")
    private Date updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    private Date createdDate;

}
```

//pcode, bol, bols, eId are composite key

// Document table, Here some more interesting realtionshipp between Project,Document is "pcode, bol, bols, eId  + did"

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class DocumentId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 458933256L;

    @Column(name = "PROJECT_CODE")
    private Integer pCode;

    @Column(name = "BOL")
    private String bol;

    @Column(name = "BOLS")
    private String bols;

    @Column(name = "EID")
    private Integer eId;

    @Column(name = "DID")
    private String dId;
}
```

//Document table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
@Data
public class Documents implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 14578523695L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private DocumentId documentId;

    @Column(name = "JUR")
    private String jur;

    @Column(name = "DSEQUENCE")
    private Integer dSequence;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DATE")
    private Date updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    private Date createdDate;

}
```

> Relationship between two table Document is the child table of Project,
>   I would like make one to relationship from Project side. 
>    From Document to project also fine

how can i map one to one relationship between tables ??

Answer (score 1):

1. Document table should have the key columns of Project entity (pCode, bol etc..)
2. Add this member on the Document class:

   ```
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "pCode", referencedColumnName = "PROJECT_CODE"),
                 @JoinColumn(name = "bol", referencedColumnName = "BOL"),
                 @JoinColumn(name = "bols", referencedColumnName = "BOLS"),
                 @JoinColumn(name = "eid", referencedColumnName = "EID")})
   @MapsId("projectId")
   private Project project;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , is it possible to make realtionship from Project side ??

Comment: Yes, same goes to the other side. make sure to add DocumenId columns in Project table

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment. But how is this a one-to-one mapping as having the column DID in the Document table proves that you can have multiple documents for the same project by having different DID. I am not sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30635542)